# Python: htmllib.HTMLParser problem with url extraction when <div> present

Tags: python, url, html-parsing

I have found a strange thing with htmllib.HTMLParser

here is a code

```
import htmllib, formatter, sys

class LinksExtractor(htmllib.HTMLParser):

        def __init__(self, formatter) :
                htmllib.HTMLParser.__init__(self, formatter)
                self.links = []

        def start_a(self, attrs) :
                # process the attributes
                if len(attrs) > 0 :
                        for attr in attrs :
                                if attr[0] == "href" :
                                        self.links.append(attr[1])

        def get_links(self) :
                return self.links

format = formatter.NullFormatter()
htmlparser = LinksExtractor(format)

data = '''<div style="align:left; text-align:justify; width:500px; color:#000">Nice!<br/>
        <a href="http://example.com/">some anchor</a>
</div>'''

htmlparser.feed( data )
htmlparser.close()

links = htmlparser.get_links()

for url in links:
        print url
```

and no links found :(
When <div> tags was removed all works fine. Who knows where is the bug - in code or in my DNA?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not the div tag, but infact the < br/ > tag. Parser looks for start tag in the format < X > and end tag in the format  < /X >. And for tags like < p > abd < br > it doesnt mind having no end tag. Hence replace < /br > with < br > and you should be fine.

Ofcourse if you need to have this custom html working you need to override other HTMLParser like start_tagname() ,end_tagname() and do_tagname()

Sorry about the spaces, its losing format

Comment: Lot of thanks for answer. You right, it's <br/> tag problem. Seems I have to rewrite parser...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure why, but the library is ok with your div tags - it's the

```
<br/>
```

tag that it doesn't like
...if you replace

```
<br/>
```

with

```
<br />
```

(ie. add a space after "br"), then it works as you expect

...so you could just globally replace them all:

```
data = '''<div style="align:left; text-align:justify; width:500px; color:#000">Nice!<br/>
        <a href="http://example.com/">some anchor</a>
</div>'''.replace('<br/>','<br />')
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, you right, it's <br/> tag problem, but html code is not mine. I just fetch html pages and try to extract all links from it. I don't know, maybe it's not a single problem in this way to parse html and I don't want to catch another while production use. It's better to rewrite parser in other way.